# SQL Server 2005 Profiler How do you view the entire Stored Procedure Chain

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

SQL Server 2005 Profiler shows that a Stored Procedure (SP) was called and what variables were passed. However I don't know how to get profiler to show me subsequent calls. By this I mean when SP A calls SP B and SP B calls SP C.

Is there a way to get profiler to show this chain?

Thanks

Comment: Good question.  I have tried to debug this kind of issue before with all kinds of problems.  As I recall the issue I had was related to distributed transaction as i was calling the SP's through a linked server.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can enable the [SP:StmtCompleted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189570.aspx) event to see each statement inside the procedures, insluding calls to other procedures. Note that this is quite heavy tracing, should be used exclusively for debugging purposes, not on live servers.